# golang time.Format(time.UnixDate) return different value in different golang versions

Tags: date, go

time.Format(time.UnixDate) is different in different environment

In windows, golang version: go version `go1.16.4 windows/amd64`

time.Format(time.UnixDate): **Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 +0000 2021**

While in `WSL`, golang verison: go version `go1.15.13 linux/amd64`

time.Format(time.UnixDate): **Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 UTC 2021**

I think "Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 UTC 2021" is the right one.
But why "Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 +0000 2021" can be generated?

My test code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func main() {
    now := time.Now() 
    fmt.Println("now UnixDate: " + now.Format(time.UnixDate))
    
    expireTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2021-01-30T23:00:00+00:00")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("time.RFC3339: " + time.RFC3339)
    fmt.Println(expireTime)
    text, _ := expireTime.MarshalText()
    fmt.Println("MarshalText: " + string(text))
    fmt.Println("expireTime.Format: " + expireTime.Format(time.UnixDate))
    fmt.Println("time.UnixDate: " + time.UnixDate)
}
```

In windows, golang version: go version go1.16.4 windows/amd64

its output:

```
now UnixDate: Fri Jun 25 15:46:43 CST 2021
time.RFC3339: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
2021-01-30 23:00:00 +0000 +0000
MarshalText: 2021-01-30T23:00:00Z
expireTime.Format: Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 +0000 2021
time.UnixDate: Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

while in WSL, golang verison: go version go1.15.13 linux/amd64

```
now UnixDate: Fri Jun 25 08:25:20 UTC 2021
time.RFC3339: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
2021-01-30 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
MarshalText: 2021-01-30T23:00:00Z
expireTime.Format: Sat Jan 30 23:00:00 UTC 2021
time.UnixDate: Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

Comment: You omitted the `now UnixDate:` from the WSL output, can you add that?

Comment: now UnixDate: Fri Jun 25 08:25:20 UTC 2021. Sorry for that.

Comment: OK, then this is a duplicate. In your WSL the local timezone is UTC, so `expireTime` will have UTC zone because the parsed time has the same offset. In your Windows  you have `CST` local zone, so `expireTime` will have a "fabricated" zone after parsing, having `0` offset. That's why formatting later the time one will output `UTC` and the other the `0` offset.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for you help. I understand now.